# What is the best way to handle many custom exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, design-patterns

Due to some requirements, in my cpp library I need to add many custom exceptions(Almost 50+), so I am thinking to write a custom exceptions like below,

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <exception>

 using namespace std;

 class ScaleException: public exception
 {
   virtual const char* what() const throw()
   {
     return "My ScaleException happened";
   }
 };



 class NotExistException: public exception
 {
   virtual const char* what() const throw()
   {
     return "NotExistException";
   }
 };

 class StateException: public exception
 {
   virtual const char* what() const throw()
   {
     return "StateException";
   }
 };


 int main ()
 {


   try
   {
     throw ScaleException();
   }
   catch (exception& e)
   {
     cout << e.what() << endl;
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

But my worry is that I need to write so many custom exceptions class (I have almost 50+ different kind of exceptions, so I may endup writing those many exception class) , is there any way to define all in one or few classes, and it would easy and meaning full to throw the exceptions.

What kind of design I should have?

Comment: As it stands, I feel like this question is very broad and hard to answer correctly - you may have more luck over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You only presented a few examples, but perhaps you'd benefit from examining the [standard exception class hierarchy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception). Maybe some of them could be used to represent the same ideas as your custom one? Just construct with a custom message.

Comment: How to use standard exception with custom message ?

Comment: @user3607698 - `std::logic_error` and `std::runtime_error` accept a custom message as a constructor parameter, for one.

Comment: I want some design like this : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/runtime_error/ , but dont know the implementation of range_error and runtime_error class, is that implementation is available for reference?

Comment: I would be more concerned about how to catch these. Would I have to use 50 different catch clauses to tell them apart? Or could there be groups of "similar" exceptions derived from a common base? Like invalid_parameter --> out_of_range --> too_small.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider two options:

1. Having a single exception class, with a constructor that takes exception-specific data:

   ```
   namespace mylib {

   using exception_kind_t = unsigned;
   enum ExceptionKind : exception_kind_t {
       InvalidScale = 0,
       NonExistentResource = 1,
       Whatever = 2
   }; 

   class exception : public std::exception {
   public:
       static const char*[] messages = {
           "invalid scale", 
           "non-existent resource",
           "whatever"
       };
       exception(exception_kind_t kind) : kind_(kind) { }
       exception(const exception&) = default;
       exception(exception&&) = default;
       exception_kind_t kind() const { return kind_; }
       virtual const char* what() const throw() {
           return messages[kind_];
       }
   protected:
       exception_kind_t kind_;
   };
   } // namespace mylib
   ```
2. Differentiating exception classes using a template parameter:

   ```
   namespace mylib {

   using exception_kind_t = unsigned;
   enum ExceptionKind : exception_kind_t {
       InvalidScale = 0,
       NonExistentResource = 1,
       Whatever = 2
   }; 

   template <exception_kind_t Kind>
   class exception : public std::exception {
       static const char*[] messages = {
           "invalid scale", 
           "non-existent resource",
           "whatever"
       };
       exception_kind_t kind() const { return Kind; }
       virtual const char* what() const throw() {
           return messages[Kind];
       }
   };

   } // namespace mylib
   ```

PS - I have tested this code, just scribbled it here, so focus on the idea rather than the specifics.

Comment: its not compiling, "[Error] expected nested-name-specifier before 'unsigned'"

Comment: A pointer to a string literal can be a template argument as well. So you could simplify even further.

Comment: I am little new to cpp, could you please post compilable code

Comment: @YSC: Yeah, edited.

Comment: thanks, its compiling, still I did not understand the use of exception_kind_t kind() const { return Kind; } this and how to call this kind method?

Comment: @user3607698: That's a sort-of-a-getter method - same as in the version where `kind_` is a protected member. When you're using a template parameter, it's not trivial to get its value otherwise. You might have use for this value when handling the exception, as opposed to merely the description string.

Comment: @einpoklum, I need to add extra String while calling exception, User may call with or with out string, like this exception<template>("string") or exception<template>() , how to make this both work ?

Comment: @user3607698: No problem, just add an extra string field to the exception, and modify the constructors to take that string. You could also opt for a [string_view](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) instead of a string, to avoid allocation and copying (pre-C++17 implementation: [here](https://github.com/martinmoene/string-view-lite)).